# sfDependantSelectPlugin "no release available for plugin..."

Tags: php, ajax, cmd, symfony-1.4

While Installing the sfDependentSelectPlugin-0.1.6, we find a notice like:

[[[no release available for plugin "sfDependantSelectPlugin" in state "stable"]]]

Is it a normal notice? or we have to do something to resolve it before continuing to develope it?

Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

It is normal notice, this plugin have only alpha version, this is why you have this notice. I install it using NetBeans :

```
 symfony plugin:install  sfDependentSelectPlugin --release="0.1.6"
```

Check  [this](http://www.techrecipes.net/programming/symfony/install-unstable-plugin)

Comment: thx, it's operational now
but i found a second problem:
While using it, my second list doesn't load any information relative to the first. i followed the tutorial existing in :
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin

Comment: thx, it's operational now
but i found a second problem:
While using it, my second list doesn't load any information relative to the first. i followed the tutorial existing in :
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin

can i know why? or what i have to modify??

Comment: Can yuo tell more about "list"?

Comment: I have a list which shows all public_sectors, the second list load all parent_sectors related to the first. that means that parent_sectors(id_par_sect,id_pub_sect, name...) depend on what we select in Public_sectors(id_pub_sect,name...)

Comment: Sorry,I can not help you with this (